# Save multiple records for one model in CakePHP

Tags: cakephp, save, cakephp-1.3

I would like to save several records for one model. This would have been done pretty easily with `saveAll()` if it hadn't been for a problem:

I have a notification form, where I select multiple users from a `<select>` and two fields, for subject and content respectively. Now, when I output what `$this->data` contains, I have:

```
Array([Notification] => Array
    (
        [user_id] => Array
            (
                [0] => 4
                [1] => 6
            )

        [subject] => subject
        [content] => the-content-here
    )
)
```

I've read on Cake 1.3 book, that in order to save multiple records for a model, you have to have the `$this->data` something like:

```
Array([Article] => Array(
        [0] => Array
            (
                        [title] => title 1
                    )
        [1] => Array
            (
                        [title] => title 2
                    )
            )
)
```

So, how do I 'share' the subject and content to all selected users?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First off, this database design needs to be normalized.

It seems to me like a `Notification` can have many `User`s related to it. At the same time, a `User` can have many `Notification`s. Therefore,

- Introduce a join table named users_notifications.
- Implement the HABTM Relationship: Notification **hasAndBelongsToMany** User

In the view, you can simply use the following code to automagically bring up the multi-select form to grab user ids:

```
echo $this->Form->input('User');
```

The data that is sent to the controller will be of the form:

```
Array(
    [Notification] => Array
        (
            [subject] => subject
            [content] => contentcontentcontentcontentcontentcontent
        ),
    [User] => Array
        (
            [User] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 4
                    [1] => 6
                )
         )
)
```

Now, all you have to do is called the saveAll() function instead of save().

```
$this->Notification->saveAll($this->data);
```

And that's the Cake way to do it!

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I thought that having a Users hasMany Notifications is enough. But now I understand that I also need a Notifications hasMany Users is order to properly submit the form. Have only a question, though: I have a Users hasAndBelongsToMany Notifications relationship, and I have the UsersController and the NotificationsController. Do I need the UsersNotificationsController for something? Or I'll use $this->User->Notification, respectively $this->Notification->User when the relationship is needed?

Comment: You might need the model UsersNotification if you begin to add complexity to the join relationship.

Comment: For example: If you want to store whether a user has read a notification, your join table becomes: id - user_id - notification_id - read. Now, you would have to model this "through" relationship as a separate entity. You can read more about it here: http://book.cakephp.org/view/1039/Associations-Linking-Models-Together#hasMany-through-The-Join-Model-1650

Comment: Thanks again. Still, I have one more question: why are all associations in the join table deleted when a new association is inserted in the table? It doesn't make any sense to me. And to stop this 'wierd' behaviour, I must have `'unique' = false` in my HABTM's relationship define array?

Comment: HABTM relationships are based on the Post-Tag analogy, where posts have unique tags (same tag doesn't appear twice). So, if you'd want to edit your post's tags, this behavior wouldn't be weird at all! :)

Using 'unique' = false is the right way to go. It's used when adding new individual tags to a post.

Comment: Thank you for clarifying :) I'll make the changes you suggested and if I have problems, I will ask again - hope you don't mind :)

Answer (score 6):

Those values have to be repeat like this

```
Array([Notification] => Array(
        [0] => Array
            (
                        [user_id] => 4
                        [subject] => subjects
                        [content] => content
                    )
        [1] => Array
            (
                        [user_id] => 6
                        [subject] => subject
                        [content] => contents
                    )
            )
)


$this->Notification->saveAll($data['Notification']); // should work
```

If you don't pass any column value, this cake will just ignore it

Answer (score 4):

You're going to have to massage your form's output to suit `Model::saveAll`. In your controller:

```
function action_name()
{
    if ($this->data) {

        if ($this->Notification->saveMany($this->data)) {
            // success! :-)
        } else {
            // failure :-(
        }
    }
}
```

And in your model:

```
function saveMany($data)
{
    $saveable = array('Notification'=>array());

    foreach ($data['Notification']['user_id'] as $user_id) {

        $saveable['Notification'][] = Set::merge($data['Notification'], array('user_id' => $user_id));
    }

    return $this->saveAll($saveable);
}
```

The benefit here is your controller still knows nothing about your model's schema, which it shouldn't.

In fact, you could probably redefine `saveAll` in your model, which hands off correctly formatted input arrays to `parent::saveAll`, but handles special cases itself.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. It is a good suggestion to make a separate method, will do that!

Comment: I put this code on my server and it seems that the saveAll() doesn't work. The new array looks smooth, I pass it to the saveAll(), but it doesn't save anything. I removed the validation within this method but with no success. What could the problem be?

Answer (score 1):

There might be a more cakey way of doing this, but I've used this kind of technique: First, change the form so that you get an array like this:

```
Array(
    [Notification] => Array
        (
            [subject] => subject
            [content] => contentcontentcontentcontentcontentcontent
        ),
    [selected_users] => Array
        (
            [id] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 4
                    [1] => 6
                )
         )
)
```

(Just change the multiselect input's name to selected_users.id)

Then loop through the user ids and save each record individually:

```
foreach( $this->data[ 'selected_users' ][ 'id' ] as $userId ) {
    $this->data[ 'Notification' ][ 'user_id' ] = $userId;
    $this->Notification->create();  // initializes a new instance
    $this->Notification->save( $this->data );
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I thought it was a more 'cakey' method for doing this. But, I'll go the 'straight-forward' way.